# Define const generics in the where clause

Tags: function, generics, rust, where-clause, const-generics

Is there any way to define a **const generic** in the **where clause**, currently it doesn't seem to work. If there isn't, are there any plans of adding it in the future?

## My Failed Attempts

```rust
fn foo<N>()
where
    const N:usize,
{}
```

```rust
fn foo<const N>()
where
    N:usize  
{}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible.
As described in [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html) a const generic always follows the pattern

> `const IDENTIFIER : Type ( = Block | IDENTIFIER | -?LITERAL )?`

Seing as they are a completly different kind of generic from both lifetime and type parameters and the `: Type` isn't a bound like with them it's unlikely to ever be supported within `where` clauses as they are for bounds.